# How to convert exec() output to integer and perform operations

Tags: php, bash, terminal

I am running a php script to find out how many python3 processes are running on my machine. I use the following code:
`$count = exec("pgrep -c python3")`
This returns me 2 (if 2 processes are running, for example). Now I need to do mathematical operation on this output, say subtract this count from 5. When I do so and echo the output, I get nothing. I tried typecasing to int, but that won't help.

Can somebody please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can we have the other part of the code, where you do the mathematical operations.

Comment: I'm simply trying to do `die(5-(int)$count)` It returns nothing

Comment: Yes, `die(5 - (int)$count)` for sure will not echo anything, can you read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: Try this `die( strval( 5-(int)$count ) );`

Comment: strval does the job for me. You're awesome Karkouch, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post this as an answer so that I may mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function:

```
/**
 * Count the number of  processes runing based on their name
 * @param string $processus_name
 * @return integer|boolean
 */
function count_processus( $processus_name = '' ){
    $processe_name = escapeshellarg( $processus_name );
    $exit_status = 0;
    $output = '';
    $cmd = sprintf( 'pgrep -c %s', $processus_name );
    exec( $cmd, $output, $exit_status );
    if( $exit_status != 0 ){
        // Faild $output will containe the error message
        return false;
    }

    return (int)$output[0];
}
```

Comment: Sure. I'll give it a try.

Comment: note that $output can not be parsed as int as it is supposed to be an array!

Comment: Yes, you're right I forget about that, I edited the answer.